# Правильно ли проставлены запятые в тексте ниже?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, деепричастный-оборот

Правильно ли проставлены запятые в тексте?

> Полагая, что сопротивление не изменяется со временем и учитывая соотношения для заряда и тока из предыдущих формул после интегрирования выражения, получают...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В деепричастный оборот с двумя деепричастиями (*полагая и учитывая*) вклинивается придаточное предложение, относящееся к первому из них, поэтому не хватает ещё одной запятой:

*Полагая, что сопротивление не изменяется со временем, и учитывая...*